# SQL Row_Number() increase only when the value = 1 for a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having some trouble generating row_number() in my SQL query as my expectation. I have this following output of my query-

[image]

Now, I want to add row number for all rows where row number will only increase when the value in C1 is = 1. Required output as below-

[image: My Required Output]

Any help will be appreciated. TIA

Comment: can you post your query here

Comment: Its a simple query given below-

    SELECT * FROM(
     SELECT 1 AS C1
     UNION ALL SELECT 4
     UNION ALL SELECT 1
     UNION ALL SELECT 1
     UNION ALL SELECT 4
     UNION ALL SELECT 1
     UNION ALL SELECT 3
     UNION ALL SELECT 4
    )A

Comment: how are you supposed to identify the original order of the rows?  sql-server doesn't guarantee to maintain the rows in the same order inserted.  Do you have another identity, key, or date column or something to be able to know why the first order should be 1,4,1,1,4,1,3,4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table Variable:

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (C1 INT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (1),(4),(1),(1),(4),(1),(3),(4)
```

SQL 2008 Version

```
;WITH cteSimulateAnOriginalIdentityKey AS (
    SELECT
       C1
       ,OriginalOrder = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM
       @Table
)

, cteC1RowNumber AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,C1RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY OriginalOrder)
    FROM
       cteSimulateAnOriginalIdentityKey
)

SELECT
    C1
    ,RN = ISNULL((SELECT MAX(C1RowNumber) FROM cteC1RowNumber r2 WHERE r2.C1 = 1 AND r2.OriginalOrder <= r1.OriginalOrder),1)
FROM
    cteC1RowNumber r1
ORDER BY
    OriginalOrder
```

SQL 2012+ version

```
;WITH cteSimulateAnOriginalIdentityKey AS (
    SELECT
       C1
       ,OriginalOrder = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM
       @Table
)

, cteC1RowNumber AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,C1RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY OriginalOrder)
    FROM
       cteSimulateAnOriginalIdentityKey
)

SELECT
    C1
   ,RN = ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN C1 = 1 THEN C1RowNumber END) OVER (ORDER BY OriginalOrder),1)
FROM
    cteC1RowNumber
ORDER BY
    OriginalOrder
```

RESULT:

```
C1  RN
1   1
4   1
1   2
1   3
4   3
1   4
3   4
4   4
```

If you in fact have another column by which to maintain the desired original order you don't need the first cte which is simply simulating that column

Comment: @mkRabbani I suppose the one question that remains is what do you want to do when your data set doesn't Start with C1 = 1.  Just have it be 1 and then the first C1 be 1 as well or would the first C1 be 2?

Comment: Thanks Matt. Indeed my data set will always contain a 1 at the beginning. Your codes are appropriate regarding my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT C1,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C1 ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) RN
FROM TableNAme
```

Comment: I can not change the output order by adding ORDER BY C

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have another column(s) in your query by which you determine the order of rows; without such a criteria, your whole question is pointless.

The query below will work on SQL Server 2012 or later versions:

```
declare @Table table (
    Id int identity(1,1) not null,
    C1 int
);

insert into @Table(C1) values (1),(4),(1),(1),(4),(1),(3),(4);

select t.C1,
    sum(case t.C1 when 1 then 1 else 0 end) over(order by t.Id) as [RN]
from @Table t;
```